# Enterprise Keyword not updating in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Any idea how to inject values to the Enterprise Keywords column of a List / Doc Lib Item using code?

Tried the following, it didn't give any error, but that column wouldn't update, while the Title did.

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://testweb"))
{
  using (var web = site.OpenWeb("testsite1"))
  {
    var list = web.Lists["testlist1"];

    var item = list.AddItem();
    item["Title"] = string.Format("Injected from code on {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    item["Enterprise Keywords"] = "1;#Opera|4eed0518-9676-4afc-be20-9027b3b69e42";
    item.Update();
  }
}
```

In this code, Opera keyword has been added previously, I've checked it against the TaxonomyHiddenList list as well using code to extract the correct ID and IdForTerm (the GUID).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a taxonomy field value the approach is a little bit different. Please try:

```
TaxonomyField entKeyword = (TaxonomyField)item.Fields["Enterprise Keywords"];
TaxonomyFieldValue term = new TaxonomyFieldValue("1;#Opera|4eed0518-9676-4afc-be20-9027b3b69e42");
entKeyword.SetFieldValue(item,term);
```

in stead of:

```
item["Enterprise Keywords"] = "1;#Opera|4eed0518-9676-4afc-be20-9027b3b69e42";
```

Comment: This worked.  I am using it with the TaxonomySession.GetTerms(...).